# How do I create a function that takes a function as input and returns this function modified but with same input arguments?

Tags: r, function

Let for example function g be defined by `g(x):=x+1`.

I want to programm a function f which can take a arbitrary function `h(a_1,...,a_n)` (`a_1,...,a_n` being the arguments) and returns the function `g(h)`. So that 
`f(h)(a_1=1,...,a_n=n)` works and returns the same as `g(h(a_1=1,...,a_n=n))`.

So we need something like

f <- (h){ 
  - get the arguments of h and put them in a list/vector arg(I found functions   that do that) 
  - return a function ´f(h)´ that has the elements of arg as arguments. (I am not sure how to do that) 
}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question since what you wrote seems ok but is that what you are looking for?

```
somelistorvector <- list(a = 1, b = 2)

fct <- function(arg){
  arg[[1]] + arg[[2]]       # arg[["a"]] + arg[["b"]] could also work
}

fct(somelistorvector)

[1] 3
```

Also are the arguments always going to be `a and b` or element `1 and 2` ?

Comment: My goal is to create a function that takes functions as input and returns a modified function with the same arguments and same argument names. So function f takes function g1(name1,name2) and returns function g2(name1, name2) .

Comment: Sorry it isn't really clear. Maybe you should try adding this to your original question!

Comment: @drogan It's alright :D This way there's more chance you get help!